# Why has Google Chrome switched to dark mode?

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome

So I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and Chrome 114 which appears to have just updated. My Chrome crashed so I restarted it and not hey presto its defaulted to a Dark Mode. I've tried to go into Settings > Appearance > GTK Button but no affect and even Google search pages are now in black/dark.

I'd quite like to revert it back and wondering what I can do about it?

Comment: Is you desktop dark? If so and you switch to light does chrome do that too? I am still on 113 btw. and on 23.04 so ... this might not be an Ubuntu issue and more a Chrome issue.

Comment: Yes I think so - so perhaps Chrome is now using my Dark mode and assuming I want that there too but annoying - as I dont!

Comment: install a white theme ;) I have all black but need white browser for bank barcode scan so I use a white theme.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - I like Ubuntu to be on dark mode but I like to keep my browsers in light mode. I tried installing a light theme but when I open my developer tools, they are in dark mode still and even the tooltips and context menus are still all in dark mode. I couldn't find any settings to ignore the system settings.

Answer (score 1):

Since Chrome 114+, Chrome started to properly respect 'dark mode' in linux (https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/1acb960204281157ac3a583a07ce07e2754ea42b).

What I've done to get it back to a light theme, while preserving my dark theme in the desktop environment, using dconf editor and set    */org/gnome/desktop/interface/color-scheme* to "prefer-light". Hope this helps you in your case!

Comment: "Properly respect" is not how I would describe this. More like "built with nonsensical assumptions". Just because I like dark window borders, that does not mean I want text documents to be rendered with a black background.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Tested on Ubuntu 22.04

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-light`

Comment: `gsettings` is just an alternate way of editing the dconf database as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/1471996/158442

Comment: You should've known that not everybody has that file or have the will to keep it. So this one-liner is okay unless you know any cons.

Comment: What file? Will to keep what? I'm saying that your oneliner is just an alternate command to do something that has already been suggested (change dconf setting X to Y - which you can do using the dconf editor gui, the `dconf` command or the `gsettings` command). Obviously there's no point to having a separate answer for each way of doing that. You should be at the least upvoting the existing answer and possibly commenting or editing it instead of posting a new one confirming their answer.

Comment: The previous answer doesn't describe a definite command to do that with "dconf". Only an idea. I come here for the answer "run that command" and I figured out a concrete step on how to achieve the goal that I shared and it works. I see no point in disliking that answer, but that's up to you how to perceive my answer.

Comment: "Dconf editor" is a GUI application to edit dconf settings. It's describing the exact thing to do, not just "an idea".

Comment: I don't have a dconf in my apps search. Then the previous answer must've been more specific on actions.

Comment: Can you explain why this works, what this setting means, and what else it might affect?